# Convert factor that includes "." to numeric

Tags: r

I'm using a dataset that has periods (`.`) in place of `NA`s. Right now, the column I'm looking at is a factor with levels `1`, `2`, and `.`. I'm trying to take a mean, and obviously, na.rm isn't working. I went back and cleaned the data by changing the periods to NAs (`pe94[pe94 == "."] <- NA`), and that appeared to work. However, `mean` can't take the mean of a factor, and when I convert the factor to a numeric, the `NA`s become `3`s. How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: Your approach sets the _labels_ of `.` elements to `NA`, rather than the level itself. Try `levels(pe94)[match('.', levels(pe94))] <- NA`, then coerce to numeric.

Comment: @jbaums - The `NA` assignment by OP seems to work okay for me.

Comment: It does, but 1s and 2s will likely become 2s and 3s unless you first coerce to character or `droplevels`, I think: `as.numeric(as.character(myfactor))`

Comment: If you're not too far down the track of analysis/manipulation, you might consider flagging the `.` as NA to begin with, when reading in the data. e.g. `read.table(..., na.strings=c('.', 'NA'))`

Comment: @jbaums - I wouldn't ever consider it a safe prospect to do `as.numeric(myfactor)` and hope it matched what was required. OP stated that their `NA`s became `3`s - I don't see how that is possible as the original `NA` call worked fine.

Comment: @jbaums using na.strings worked, thanks!

Comment: @thelatemail if you want to test using the actual dataset, you can download it at http://microdata.worldbank.org/index.php/catalog/617 (I used the K02 variable in the reg11 dataset).

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar issues (and other issues) converting factors into numbers for mathematical analysis.  However, I found a fairly simple solution that seems to work.  Hope this helps ...

```
#Script to convert factor data to numeric data without loss or alterations of values

#Samlpe data frame with factor variables represented by numbers 
factor.vector1<-factor(x=c(111,222,333,444,555))
thousands<-c("1,000","2,000","3,000","4,000","5,000")
factor.vector2<-factor(x=thousands)
df<-data.frame(factor.vector1, factor.vector2)

#Numbers as factors without comma place holders
#1st convert dataset to character data type
df[,1]<-as.character(df[,1])
#2nd convert dataset to numeric data type
df[,1]<-as.numeric(df[,1])

#Numbers as factors WITH comma place holders 
#If data contains commas in the numbers (e.g. 2,000) use gsub to remove commas
#If commas are not removed before conversion, the value containing commas will become NA
df[,2]<-gsub(",", "", df[,2])
#1st convert dataset to character data type
df[,2]<-as.character(df[,2])
#2nd convert dataset to numeric data type
df[,2]<-as.numeric(df[,2])
```